# Como soluciono esto, es en arduino warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

Tags: arduino

```
if(song != last_song){ //Reproduce el audio una unica vez siempre que se haya cambiado de cancion

   switch(song)
   {
      case 1: Audio.play("dross2.wav"); Serial.println("Cancion 1"); break;
      case 2: Audio.play("vegeta.wav"); Serial.println("Cancion 2"); break;
      case 3: Audio.play("faded.wav", 30); Serial.println("Cancion 3 desde el segundo 30"); break;
   }

last_song = song;
}
```

> Cita en bloque
>   el error es en los casos.

C:\Users\Andrea\Desktop\Arduino-WAV\Arduino-WAV.ino:86:38: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

```
   case 1: Audio.play("dross2.wav"); Serial.println("Cancion 1"); break;
```

gracias

Comment: Bienvenida Andrea, podrías poner la versión del Arduino IDE que estás usando???

Answer (score 0):

La impresión de los datos es de una cadena de caracteres, por una cuestión de conversión te sale ese error(Al parecer ya esta en desuso). Seria bueno que intentes castearlo de esta forma para evitar estos problemas:

```
case 1: Audio.play("dross2.wav"); Serial.println( (char *) "Cancion 1"); break;
```

o

```
case 1: Audio.play("dross2.wav"); Serial.println( (const char *) "Cancion 1"); break;
```